# Show two body Calendars In one Input

Tags: html, calendar

Is there a way to create a calendar input like the example in the image below?

I have used `<input type="date">` but it only shows content of one calendar and if want two it must have two `<input type="date">` , but here I want one `< input>` can display two calendar bodies and can select date on calendar body, is there a way?

```
<form action="/check_calendar.php">
  <label>Calendar :</label>
  <input type="date" name="calendar">
  <input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

Example :

[image: example]

Comment: from where did u get that image?

Comment: try `<input type='week'>`

Comment: @GhostOps I took a picture on the contributor pngtree site in the Revenue Management section

Comment: @GhostOps Does not work

Comment: then pls do some inspect on that... u will find something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2021 - 01/15/2021" />
    </body>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker(
                {
                    ssingleDatePicker: 'true',
                    showShortcuts: 'false',
                    showTopbar: 'false'
                }
            );
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this magical answer. In case if anyone don't need already selected months data i.e. Jan2021-Feb2021, just remove the **value** attribute from the input field and it'll work according to the current data & months.

Answer (score 0):

Use date range picker. You will achieved it very easily.